# Когда идёт разбор ViewState в жизненном цикле?

Tags: asp.net

Немного не пойму... написано, что разбор идёт в Init, то есть контролам назначаются все свойства. Но, например, я изменил кликом по кнопке её название c Button на Knopka. На постбэк же ушёл старый viewstate c Value=Button, как оно возвращет knopka?

Comment: или viewstate генерируется из запроса формы на сервере?

Answer (score 3):

То что Вам нужно очень хорошо описано на [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic2). Также есть пример схожий с Вашим.

[image: жизненный цикл]

Во втором шаге четко видно, что при Postback-e, перед тем как проходит Rendering, ViewState сохраняется заново, что и дает необходимый эффект в виде смены текста.